# Alternative to jquery .inarray?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I love how inarray, searchs an array without looping, but it only does exact/precise matches, where if i used the .match, i can do partial matches, but that requires a loop.

Is there any way to search an array for partial matches, without looping?

There are 2 arrays, 1 to be searched for, the 2nd to replace the text/values if a partial or full match is found in the 1st.

The goal is to have the fastest way to search the array for partial or full matches.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I need the index, to get the position in 1st array, to find the replacement text in array 2. So the logic is, find partial match in 1st array, get the position, use the position to get the replacement value in 2nd array, and then go ahead and do replace....The replacement part i got, just fast partial array look up.

Comment: Any other way to do a partial search of text in an array without looping?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, `.inArray()` of course loops over the Array if `Array.prototype.indexOf()` is not available:

**snippet**

```
inArray: function( elem, array ) {
    if ( array.indexOf ) {
        return array.indexOf( elem );
    }

    for ( var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++ ) {
        if ( array[ i ] === elem ) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
},
```

**snippet**

If you just want to know whether or not an entry is contained by an Array, you may just want to `.join()` it and use the `String.prototype.indexOf()`.

This of course, can't return an index anymore. So you would need to write your own logic. Could be done easily by modifying the above code. For instance:

```
Array.prototype.ourIndexOf = function(v) {
    for ( var i = 0, length = this.length; i < length; i++ ) {
       if ( typeof this[i] === 'string' && this[i].indexOf(v) > -1 ) {
            return i;
       }
    }
    return -1;
};

['Foobar', 'baseball', 'test123'].ourIndexOf('base') // === 1
```

Comment: @jAndy: It would still be possible to get the index by using `.join()`. How? Using a separator `.join("|")` then splitting the string by the value you're looking for (you'd get two strings: everything before the value and everything after it). After that all you'd have to do is count the number of separators in the first split string. Voila. Index obtained.

Comment: Is this some of the javascript that jquery is made of? I've seen code like this before, never understood where it comes from.

Comment: @Robert: you're right, but it's odd anyway. @crosenblum: The first snippet comes right from the jQuery source, yes.

Comment: @jAndy: Well if the array was long with short strings it could become feasible. Counting separators would be a mere regular expression count of matches basically. So nothing complex in my opinion.

Comment: @Robert: I didn't say complex, just odd.

Comment: Okay Robert, that kind of makes sense, but in terms of searching a string, are there ways to get partial matches vs full matches? Like if you were searching the string "Peaches and pearls are a girls love and joy" and was searching for the word pearl to replace it with the word diamond. I know .match does exact matches, but how would this do partial matches?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what are you trying to do, you may find some [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) functions useful:

1. `detect` (returns the first element matching your criteria)
2. `select` (returns all matching elements)
3. `any` (returns true if any element matches)
4. `each` (iterates over elements)
5. `map` (transforms an array into a new one)

There are some other functions that you may find useful.